# Sample space in probability computing

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

This is a simple example of probability computing.

There are $n$ white balls and one black ball in a box. Take the balls one by one out of the box until the black ball appears. Let $X$ denotes the number of taking times. Then $P\{ X = k\}  = \frac{1}{{n + 1}}$.

However, I can't see what the sample space $\Omega $ (ie the total set of all the possibilities of taking) is. How to explain this strictly?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For a simpler sample space, imagine not stopping, just recording when we got the black. It is convenient to assume the balls have ID numbers on them.

Comment: If by $X=k$, you mean that the person picks k-1 white balls and then the $k_{th}$ ball is black, then shouldn't it be: $P(x=k)=1/(k+1)$? Because there are total only k+1 possibility to draw k balls. And only 1 of these the desired one.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we denote the event of drawing $k$ white balls in the first $k$ trials, and then the black ball in the $(k+1)^{th}$ trial as $E_{k}$, i.e., 
\begin{eqnarray}
E_{k}=\{\underbrace{W,W,\ldots,W}_{k~times},B\},~k\geq 0,
\end{eqnarray}
where $W$ denotes a white ball and $B$ denotes the black ball. If the sample space is denoted as $\Omega$, then $\Omega$ consists of the events $\{E_{m}\}_{m=0}^{n}$.